# How to get multiple input from python checkbox form?

Tags: python, cgi

I have a list of various checkbox in html and i want to check many of them. How can i do it ?
Here is the pic of checkbox form

[image: Here is the pic of checkbox form]

Answer (score 0):

Your picture dosn't seem to be working, but I think I know what you mean.
You can't enter multiple input statements in python, but you have to do it 1 by 1. Example: `input1=input("Enter a number: ")`